# Angular JS $resource queries

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Team I am very new to angular JS and java script. I was looking at Angular JS documentation for $resource and I have following queries.

Given below is the service which is written in $resource.

```
var services = angular.module('ngdemo.services', ['ngResource']);
services.factory('UserFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/ngdemo/web/users/:id', {}, {
        show: { method: 'GET' },
        update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'} },
        delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'} }
    })
});
```

Calling place.

```
$scope.createNewUser = function () {
    UsersFactory.create($scope.user)                
}
```

1) I was not able to understand how we can pass $scope.user to this create function. How does it happen ?

**SECOND**

```
var CreditCard = $resource(
    '/user/:userId/card/:cardId', 
    {userId:123, cardId:'@id'}, 
    charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}} 
});
```

**At one place it was calling the function like**

```
var newCard = new CreditCard({number:'0123'});
newCard.name = "Mike Smith";
newCard.$save();
```

1) How can we create new instance of credit card what does it return ?

2) How we can pass argument {number:'0123'} to it. ?

3) How name,$save method is available in this object ?